# Perpendicular linear graphs exam question

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, number-theory

A is the point with coordinates (2,1)
B is the point with coordinates (6,4)
C is the point with coordinates (3,8)

The line through the points A and B cuts the y-axis at P.

The line through the points B and C cuts the y-axis at Q.

Calculate the length of PQ.

I found out that P = $-\frac{2}{4}$ and Q = 4

But I don't know how to use that to find the length of PQ.

Thank You and Help is Appreciated

Comment: A point is defined by $2$ coordinates. So what do you mean by $P = -\frac{2}{4} $ and similarly for $Q$? If you calculate $P, Q$ correctly you can calculate the distance by applying Pythagoras's Theorem on $POQ$.

Comment: Do you mean the line through the points A and B cuts the *x-axis* at P?